# Forecast using auto.arima using exogenous variables

Tags: r, time-series, visualization, arima

I would love to be able to use the exogenous variables to help in the arima forecast. I run into issues in everyway i try to use the variables outside of the one I am trying to forecast.

I would also love for the actual plot to be more beautiful than the default r.

Error in auto.arima(datats1$Slots, seasonal = TRUE, xreg = datats1ts) : 
  xreg is rank deficient

All of the problems associated with having rank deficient dataframe or matrix do not hold. There are no linear combinations in the dataset.

```
#Load Data
datats1 <- read.csv("ProjectTS2.CSV") # Time Series I want to forecast
xreg <- read.csv("ProjectTS4.CSV") #Data is want to use as exogenous

datats1$Slots <- ts(datats1$slots, start=2015,frequency=365)

dfTS<-as.matrix(ts(xreg))
new<-auto.arima(datats1$slots,seasonal=TRUE,xreg=dfTS)

seas_fcast <- forecast(new, h=30)
ts.plot(seas_fcast,xlim=c(2018,2018.2))
```

Comment: You will have to post the data if you want any help. Also use autoplot(), not ts.plot()

Comment: what is the best way to post data on here?

Comment: try `dput`, which produces R structure of your data